# c++ указатели //

Tags: c++

(void*)pa
(int)pa
Что они делают? как я понял (void*)pa - адрес строки указателя а вот про (int)pa не могу найти ничего

Comment: Это - приведение типов - грубо, превращение значение `pa` в указатель `void*` и в целое число `int`. Не более того.

Comment: pa это уже указатель , (int)pa оно выдаст число какое то случайное верно?

Comment: (int)pa выдаст значение адреса соответствующей ячейки памяти. Любой указатель - это адрес чего-либо в памяти.

Comment: Нет, вернет указатель в виде числа. Не случайное число, а именно указатель как число. Обрежет, кстати, если размер указателя больше размера `int`.

Comment: @kavo нет это великий обман, это не адрес в памяти, а адрес в виртуальной памяти!

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, нет, это вы знаете, в какой ОС (с виртуальной памятью или нет) вы запускаете программу. Компилятор никаких предположений (ну, почти никаких) на этот счет не делает.

Comment: @avp это сказки, во всех осях память виртуальная. Ну разве что только в каких-то вымерающих ещё не так.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, есть много микроконтроллеров (и кстати, любителей автоматизировать свой коттедж на них), есть firmware чипов (работает еще до загрузки ОС), да много чего еще есть в этом мире...

Comment: @avp а ещё есть компы в музеях... Но вот большинство программ работают именно с виртуальной памятью.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, ну,  с тем, что 99.999...% пишуших программы работает в виртуальной памяти (и большинство из них о другой не знают) никто не спорит

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае выражение `(type)var` - это унаследованное из C приведение значения `var` к типу `type`.

Поэтому у вас

`(void*)pa` - приведение значения в переменной `pa` к типу указателя `void*`, а
`(int)pa`- приведение значения в переменной `pa` к целочисленному типу `int`.